# Запуск питон программы в фоновом режиме

Tags: python

Подскажите, как в Windows запустить питон скрипт в фоновом режиме, как отдельный процесс...

Comment: Так же, как любую другую программу. Операционная система какая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если не хочется, что бы открывалась консоль (я так понимаю, это и будет "фоновым режимом"), то просто переименуйте .py в .pyw. 
Но так как теперь консоли  не будет, то всякие print и  другие подобные операции вывода в консоль не будут работать.